# Is there a built-in way to remove account enumeration from registration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I have created a new site using Jetstream and Inertia. Currently the application will return a "The email has already been taken." message if a user tries to register with an existing email. Notwithstanding timing analysis, I would like to keep the existence of user accounts private. Is there a way to keep the unique constraint on email but display the same outward behavior if someone registers with an existing email? Ideally, I would like to not create a second user, but email the existing user suggesting they reset their password or ignore the email.

Comment: You could customise the `unique` validation error message, however, I'm not convinced this is the correct approach. What if a user forgets they have already registered, an `email registered` error message might trigger their memory rather than cause frustration via a 'cryptic' message.

Comment: The point would be to have the exact same outward behavior if the account exists or not so the form would only kick back other errors (and not just obscure the account error). Looks like there's a lot of layers to change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Create a new validation Exception in `app/Exceptions/ExistingUserException.php`

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class ExistingUserException extends ValidationException
{

}
```

2. Break validation into 2 steps in `app/Actions/Fortify/CreateNewUser.php`, throwing the extended `ValidationException` if the form is otherwise good

```
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        $validator =  Validator::make($input, [
            'email' => ['unique:users'],
        ], ['email.unique'=>'']);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            throw new ExistingUserException($validator);
        }
```

3. Create a new middleware in `app/Http/Middleware/CatchExistingUser.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Exceptions\ExistingUserException;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class CatchExistingUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response->exception && $response->exception instanceof ExistingUserException)
        {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

4. Inject the middleware into all fortify routes via `config/fortify.php`

```
'middleware' => [CatchExistingUser::class, 'web'],
```

5. Remove the auth middleware from the verification page by overwriting the route in `routes/web.php`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\VerifyEmailViewResponse;
...
Route::get('/email/verify', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user && $user->hasVerifiedEmail())
    {
        return redirect()->intended(config('fortify.home'));
    }
    return app(VerifyEmailViewResponse::class);
})
->name('verification.notice');
```

The custom exception is not ideal but it seems cleaner than testing the validator stored in the `ValidatorException` and then removing one message if there's more than one error. I think this would be needed to allow the validation of other fields while not leaking email uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Unflux about not changing this, but if you need to you could modify `CreateNewUser.php` located at `app\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php` and change the validation message or modify the process.

The `create()` method which is responsible for creating the new user looks like:

```php
public function create(array $input)
    {
        //define custom messages
        $customValidationMessages = {
            'email.unique' => 'New Message',
        }


        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'], //email validation rules here
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ], $customValidationMessages)->validate(); //add the variable containing the custom message(s) here

        
        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        ]);
    }
```

If you need to send the user an email or customize this further I suggest you look into implementing an "After Validation Hook" which you can read about here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I agree with both you and Unflux of you that messaging is critical. Ideally, the application would still return view('auth.verify-email') after registration but send a different email (and not create the account). Looks like there's no way to do it out of the box.